# bug: Splash and Icon generator not working (Ionic and Cordova)

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

Type: bug

Platform: mobile webview

I tried to use the ionic splash and icon generator from the blog/website tutorial. It would not read my png files, even though I placed them in the root. I converted them to ai files and they would return an error saying the files could not be read (although they would open in preview and in Adobe Illustrator).

Then i used the cordova generator instructions and got this error:

> { [Error: Command failed: convert: unable to open image platforms/ios/splash/Resources/icons/icon-72@2x.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2675. convert: WriteBlob Failedplatforms/ios/splash/Resources/icons/icon-72@2x.png' @ error/png.c/MagickPNGErrorHandler/1630.
>   ] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }

Comment: If you believe this is a bug in Ionic, you should file it with them.

Comment: I've done so- just asked here because I figured someone might've come across a similar problem and solved it on their own.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using one of the latest version of **Ionic-CLI** things should work properly.

```
npm update -g ionic
```

to update your **cli**.

Once you have created your project you have to add a platform:

```
ionic platform add android

ionic platform add ios
```

In the root of your project you should find a folder called `resources`.

Place an icon file and a splash screen file:

- icon.png
- splash.png

> The icon image's minimum dimensions should be 192x192 px, and should
>   have no rounded corners.

now, from the root folder of your project:

```
ionic resources
```

and it should create the resources for all the platform defined.

Some reference [here](http://blog.ionic.io/automating-icons-and-splash-screens/) and [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/cordova/resources/).

Comment: @ChanYoongHon: sorry to hear that. this answer is for Ionic v1.x. If you're using one of the latest versions things might have changed. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tools to generate the files.
I created a NodeJS repo to facilitate the icon and splash screen generation for Ionic. So everyone can create all .png files in seconds.

https://github.com/dericeira/Icon-Splash-Resize

First, install

```
npm install icon-splash-resize
```

Then put, the files in **resources** folder

> icon.png (192x192px)
>
> splash.png (2732x2732px)

Then, run

```
node start
```

*Note you will need GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick installed*

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install graphicsmagick
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the image files in the /resources folder were .jpg, apparently, changing them to .png made everything work smoothly.